# ZooKeeperBindException when starting MiniAccumuloCluster

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I'm attempting to start up a [MiniAccumuloCluster](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/minicluster/MiniAccumuloCluster.html) for testing as described in the [Accumulo Docs](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html#_mini_accumulo_cluster):

```
TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();
File temp_dir = folder.newFolder("AccumuloTempFolder");
MiniAccumuloCluster accumulo = new MiniAccumuloCluster(tempDirectory, "password");
accumulo.start();
Instance instance = new ZooKeeperInstance(accumulo.getInstanceName(), accumulo.getZooKeepers());
Connector conn = instance.getConnector("root", new PasswordToken("password"));
```

When calling `accumulo.start()`, a ZooKeeperBindException is thrown because "Zookeeper did not start within 20 seconds." Documentation and usage notes for the MiniAccumuloCluster seem sparse - can anyone help me understand what's going wrong here? I assumed that all of the Zookeeper configuration was being handled under the covers of the MiniAccumuloCluster so I'm not even sure where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: Yeah it's 2021 and I am trying to find a solution. On a Mac here, I restarted before and it worked so it makes me think the port it selects is already taken. Trying to find the code in github for it to see if it is randomly selecting the port or hard-coded to something. I'll post something if I find a solution for others. This happens with minifluo as well cause it launches miniaccumulo.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running a docker container for the mini fluo and mini accumulo, must have been something in my local environment causing the issue. This will print out the results or put a jar in the target directory of your local machine.

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v "$(pwd)":/path/to/code/fluo- 
tour/src/main/java/ft -w /path/to/code/fluo-tour/src/main/java/ft maven:3.6.3- 
openjdk-8 mvn -q clean compile exec:java
```